# Stopping while loop with keystroke

Tags: python

Complete noob. I've read through some previous questions and tried implementing suggestions however haven't got it to work. I'm writing my first Python program and want to be able to press a key to stop the program from running aside from CTRL+C. (Forgive any indents in the code I'm pasting below as it is not necessarily the same as what I have in IDLE.)

```
x=int(input('Please Input a number... \n'))

while True:
  try:
    while x!=5:
        if x<5:
            x=x+1
            print ('Your value is now %s'%x)
            if x==5:
                print('All done, your value is 5')

        elif x>5:
            x=x-1
            print('Your value is now %s'%x)
            if x==5:
                print('All done, your value is 5')
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      import sys
      sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: The indentation of `except` is wrong

Comment: "Forgive any indents in the code I'm pasting below as it is not necessarily the same as what I have in IDLE". Then how are we supposed to fix it for you?

Comment: I'm not asking for help with indent, I'm asking for a term that will stop the loop/program..

Comment: What's wrong with using `Ctrl+C`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to detect keypresses in a non-blocking manner, but there may be third-party modules that can query your OS for keyboard state. For instance, Windows has [Pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/). Example implementation:

```
import time
import win32api

def is_pressed(key):
    x = win32api.GetKeyState(key)
    return (x & (1 << 8)) != 0

print "Beginning calculation. Press the Q key to quit."
while not is_pressed(ord("Q")):
    print "calculating..."
    time.sleep(0.1)
print "Finished calculation."
```

Comment: Instead of monitoring for a key press is it possible to define a variable, then monitor that variable throughout (without promoting the user) to see if it to a specific value? For instance c = c , and while c=c do something but when c!=c stop.

Comment: Sure. For example, if you want to monitor variable `x` and keep looping until x doesn't equal 23, you just do `while x == 23:`

Comment: This makes sense but how can I stop from prompting the user to enter a new x value each iteration? So essentially essentially any input will be put in as variable x.

Comment: Oh... That would be pretty difficult. You'd have to write some kind of `InputAccumulator` class that spawns a thread to continuously monitor the key state and add characters to its queue, possibly with custom logic to determine when an input is "new" or not (if the user presses "1" and then "2" a second later, should the variable have the value "1", then "2"? Or should It have the value "1", then "12"?). Then you'd override `__eq__` so that it compares against strings in a sensible way.

Comment: Okay, sounds like it's best to let it complete itself or ctrl c